# IIS rewrite mobile detection

Tags: regex, iis, mobile, url-rewriting

Okay, I'm trying to write a mobile detection/rewrite in IIS.  If I take the conditions out, the rewrite functions.  However, once I put the mobile detection bit in, it doesn't rewrite on mobile devices as intended (tested on an iphone and android).  Any advice here? The regex used is from here: https://gist.github.com/dalethedeveloper/1503252

```
<rule name="MobileDetect" patternSyntax="ExactMatch" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="customer-support" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
            <add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="Mobile|iP(hone|od|ad)|Android|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Kindle|NetFront|Silk-Accelerated|(hpw|web)OS|Fennec|Minimo|Opera M(obi|ini)|Blazer|Dolfin|Dolphin|Skyfire|Zune" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Rewrite" url="mobile/customer-support" />
</rule>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you need to specify the delimiters `<add input="{HTTP_USER_AGENT}" pattern="/Mobile|iP(hone|od|ad)|Android|BlackBerry...Zune/" />` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that patternSyntax needed to be set to "ECMAScript"